# K0s in LXC and ZFS issues

Tags: lxc, zfs, overlayfs, k0s

I'm trying to get K0s working in LXC (LXD) containers on Ubuntu 20.04 using ZFS and I've managed to get past the apparmor challenges (for now at least) but stuck on overlayfs issues during the install phase.

```
kernel: [1617529.987422] overlayfs: filesystem on '/var/lib/k0s/containerd/io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.overlayfs/snapshots/6371/fs' not supported as upperdir
```

Has anyone hit on this issues before and has a solution/workaround?

Regards,
Matt

Answer (score 2):

`containerd` needs to be told to use the `zfs` snapshotter:

- [k0s will not start on ZFS-based systems](https://docs.k0sproject.io/head/troubleshooting/#k0s-will-not-start-on-zfs-based-systems)
- [mount a `zfs` dataset
  inside LXD](https://discuss.linuxcontainers.org/t/mount-zfs-dataset-in-lxd/10797)

This approach will probably require the LXD container to run **privileged** & require the `zfs` modules passed through to the container.

With `k0s` it is also useful during the configuration above so `containerd` is found to add to your `bash` profile:

- `export PATH=$PATH:/var/lib/k0s/bin`

**Alternative Approach (unprivileged LXD)**

Adding an [`ext4` zvol](https://discuss.linuxcontainers.org/t/mounting-zvol-securely-in-container/4422) to the container for `containerd` will probably be less problematic & is better from a security perspective as the container can [run unprivileged](https://linuxcontainers.org/lxd/docs/master/security/). This approach works with `k3s` & `/var/lib/rancher/k3s/agent/containerd` running on LXD with `zfs`:

[image: k3s on ZFS Unprivileged LXD]

- `/var/lib/kubelet` seems to mount itself under `zfs` ok on `k3s version v1.22.7+k3s1`
- Using [rootless overlayfs](https://rootlesscontaine.rs/how-it-works/overlayfs/) for the snapshotter works now on **Ubuntu 22.04** thanks to [this patch](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/git/ubuntu/ubuntu-bionic.git/commit/fs/overlayfs?id=3b7da90f28fe1ed4b79ef2d994c81efbc58f1144). It uses less space (`639MB` versus `1.9GB`) & gives better performance than the *native* snapshotter.